# Print trace of recursive calls

Tags: c

I want to print all the recursive calls during the execution of a function for a particular invocation e.g. I've a function like this:

```
int foo(int n){
  if (n == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    return 1 + foo(n-1);
}
```

Then, for the invocation `foo(3)` I want to print:

```
foo(3) = 1 + foo(2)
       = 1 + 1 + foo(1)
       = 1 + 1 + 1 + foo(0)
       = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
       = 3
```

But I can't find out a way. What I've tried so far is modifying the recursive function like this:

```
int foo(int n){
  printf("foo(");
  int aux;
  if (n == 0)
    aux = 0;
  else
    aux = 1 + foo(n-1);
  printf(")");
  return aux;
}
```

But clearly it doesn't work the I expect it to do so that's why I'm here asking for help.

Just to clarify, this questions is not the same that the one asked in ([Tracing Recursion in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331301/tracing-recursion-in-c)) the main difference is the form of how I want to print it. Please, reconsidere the duplicate.

Comment: `printf()` triggers a system call. so in this case maybe `strace` can help you. go and try it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tracing Recursion in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331301/tracing-recursion-in-c)

Comment: this question asked before on SO. see the link below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331301/tracing-recursion-in-c). i am flaging it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Adam it's not the same question, I want to print it in this exact form. I already read that question.

Comment: As ikegami's answer demonstrates, that exact form is not a good match for a recursive implementation. So although it's possible to create that output, the code to do so is highly contrived, specific to one particular problem, and more code than the algorithm itself.

Comment: @user3386109 do you think it'd be easier in Haskell or Prolog?

Comment: To all of those who are down voting the question, could you explain why you're doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `foo` needs to print an entire line. But the information needed to do so is simply not available. You will need to provide this info.

```
char *concat(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *s = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
    memcpy(s, s1, len1);
    memcpy(s+len1, s2, len2);
    s[len1+len2] = 0;
    return s;
}

unsigned _foo(const char* prefix, unsigned n) {
   if (n) {
      printf("%sfoo(%d)\n", prefix, n);
      char *new_prefix = concat(prefix, "1 + ");
      unsigned rv = 1 + _foo(new_prefix , n-1);
      free(new_prefix);
      return rv;
   } else {
      printf("%s0\n", prefix);
      return 0;
   }
}

unsigned foo(unsigned n) {
   printf("foo(%u)\n", n);
   unsigned rv = _foo("= ", n);
   printf("= %u\n", rv);
}
```

This produces

```
foo(3)
= foo(3)
= 1 + foo(2)
= 1 + 1 + foo(1)
= 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
= 3
```

Used `unsigned` to avoid having to check for negative numbers. Error checking left to the user. Tweaking the code to get the exact output desired if left to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, what is "_foo"?

Comment: Hmm, one of the subs was accidentally renamed. Fixed